# Keyboard shortcut for a repetitive sentence

Tags: windows, text, windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm currently saving 200/300 PDFs a day (work related), they all have a sentence in that's the same, I'm unable to use Ctrl C/V as I have to copy other parts before saving.

Is there a way for me to have a keyboard shortcut that puts the sentence in for me when saving the file?

(Windows 7 and limited admin access)

Many Thanks, 
L

Comment: I like the term "limited admin access" it's like admin access but without the privileges. So basically just user access :P

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Macro editor which records keystrokes and repeats them.
This one is a free portable example (doesn't require an installation).

https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/tinytask_portable

On windows 7 you can only have one Item in the Copy&Paste Memory, so there is no other easy way than to simulate keyboard input. You can also "Drag and Drop" the sentence from somewhere else (like a website) by selecting it and then clicking on it and dragging it into the Document.
Maybe that works better for you.

Comment: Slightly confused, it's asking me to instal it?

Comment: It will ask you for an installation directory yes, but in reality it is an unpacking directory. It won't install anything, it will just unpack the content of the .exe file (it's wrongly called installation during the process though).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've understood completely your problem, but in all likelihood a clipboard manager would suit your case.
They don't (usually) allow you to have a sentence inserted automatically before saving, but they let you save many instances of "clippings" and paste them conveniently.
There are a lot of them, I personally like [Clip](https://github.com/aviaryan/Clipjump) and used also ClipX and Ditto.
Many of these clipboard managers include features to associate a specific hot key to insert a specific snippet of text.

There also programs that are focused specifically on that HotKey -> specific snippet functionality, or that include it among others.

Also, if clarified what software you're using to do these "pdf savings", it would help (it's possible that it does include facilities to include a sentence before saving).

And in any case you can almost for sure do what you want with a macro/scripting utility such as AutoHotKey (but it would usually be pretty complex if you're not already familiar with it).